# Create maintenance log display form

Tags: ms-access, vba

Creating a maintenance log database and have the data entry part running.  Want to create a form that displays the data date descending and maint type ascending.  I have one running with a datasheet in a sub form, but want to be able to control more of the formatting where each days worth of log entries are separated by a blank line and alternate the background color of each day.  I have looked around the web and read references to a grid control that seems to be in Visual Studio and not in ACCESS. 
as the days go by and entries are made to the table the data will get longer, but I want to have the ability for the user to scroll through the past few days to get a feel for maintenance issues.  Any suggestions on how to do all this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good description, but your question is fuzzy. From what I can gather it sounds like you want to use a "Continuous Form" instead of Datasheet View. This will allow you to have complete control of formatting. Not sure what the reference to the Grid Control was? But in many respects I prefer Access Datasheet View to a Grid Control.

Comment: Never used a continuous form before in ACCESS. Will do some research and respond after that>

Comment: Looked up continuous form and conditional formatting. But I want to format the color of the data in a row based on the date field in the row.  For example: there may be 5 records for the 19th and I want to have those have the same backgound color, and there may be 7 records for the 20th I want those to have a different background color, then alternate the colours by goups of same dates. Couldn't set a rule for that.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Going to add another question regarding conditional formatting.  Thanks

Comment: coditional formatting should work just fine on a continous form. I think you should just check your condition. Show us the expression you are using to format the color by taking a screen shot.

Comment: Unless I am mistaken conditional formatting only works on a row by row basis.  I need to compare the date in a row to the date that preceded it to see if it is the same date or different.  If it's the same I want one background color, if its different I want another color.  This would segregate the rows by color, and the table is sorted in date sequence descending, so records with the same date are grouped together. If there is a way of doing that I would most grateful to learn how.